# Google play not accepting my app in design for family

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I made an app "kids channel" (com.codechunks.kidsvideos.kidschannel) which works on youtube data api. app contain videos for kids like cartoons, rhymes and other learning videos. When I select "primarily child directed" and "design for family" program they are rejection my app by sending following issue of rejection

**Generic DFF eligibility**
The family-friendly experience on Designed for Families is intended to make apps easier to discover for parents and families, who expect the apps to be age appropriate. After careful consideration we have determined that your app does not meet our eligibility criteria. Apps in the program must be specifically designed for children, have a rating of E or E10+, and include relevant app information.

if anyone can help what i am doing wrong and what should i change or add to be eligible for design for family program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add age restriction, so that the videos that app shows are age appropriate, in this case for kids. Since you must be using the youtube api to show content, ensure that videos with content rating such as shown below are not displayed :

> "contentRating": {
>
> > ```
> > "ytRating": "ytAgeRestricted"
> > ```
> >
> > }

Comment: Thank you @Saint for your comment but there is no "ytRating": "ytAgeRestricted" child in youtube returned json.

Comment: When  calling https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search, adding safeSearch = strict will exclude all restricted content from the search results.

Answer (score 0):

All [the instructions for the Designed For Families program are here](https://developer.android.com/google-play/guides/families#eligibility).

There are a lot of requirements, and you have to very carefully follow them.

> Make sure that you're familiar with the policies that your app must comply with. These include [content policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), the [Developer Distribution Agreement](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html), and the [Designed for Families DDA Addendum](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/families/developer-distribution-agreement-addendum.html). Your app must also meet the [Designed for Families program requirements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7018303).

Google Play are very protective of children - I'd go through all of these carefully making sure you comply with all of them.